# getting more precise answer in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement a simple formula with python . In the case of "RLSR" there two approach to calculate the coefficient "C" by C=k^-1*y where k is the kernel matrix and y is the target value vector.

The second way is by using eigenvalues(w) and eigenvectors(v) of the kernel method and using formula :

```
Sum(u(i)*<u(i),y> / w(i) ).
```

to check the answer of the result I'm checking whether y=kc or not! in the first case it's ok , but the latter case it's not.but the problem is my c vectors in both method look the same.

output from **invers** algorithm :

```
[ 19.49840251  18.82695226  20.08390355  15.01043404  14.79353281
  16.75316736  12.88504257  16.92127176  16.77292954  17.81827473
  20.90503787  17.09359467  18.76366701  18.14816903  20.03491117
  22.56668264  21.45176136  25.44051036  30.40312692  22.61466379
  22.86480382  19.34631818  17.0169598   19.85244414  16.63702471
  20.35280156  20.58093488  22.42058736  20.54935198  19.35541575
  20.39006958  19.74766081  20.41781019  22.33858797  17.57962283
  22.61915219  22.54823733  24.96292824  22.82888425  34.18952603
  20.7487537   24.82019935  22.40621769  21.15767304  27.58919263
  18.39293156  21.55455108  18.69532341]
```

output from **second(eigendecomposition )** algorithm :

```
[ 19.25280289  18.73927731  19.77184991  14.7650427   14.87364331
  16.2273648   12.29183797  16.52024239  16.66669961  17.59282615
  20.83059115  17.02815857  18.3635798   18.16931845  20.50528549
  22.67690164  21.40479524  25.54544     30.94618128  22.72992565
  23.06289609  17.6485592   15.2758427   19.50578691  16.45571607
  20.19960765  20.35352859  22.60091638  20.36586912  18.90760728
  20.57141151  19.43677153  20.43437031  22.39310576  17.72296978
  22.82139991  22.50744791  25.10496617  22.30462867  34.80540213
  20.77064617  25.18071618  22.5500315   20.71481252  27.91939784
  18.29868659  22.00800019  18.71266093]
```

this how I have implemented it:
so let say if we have 48 samples the size of K is 48x48 , y is 48x1

```
def cpu_compute(y,k):

    w, u=LA.eigh(k)
    uDoty=np.dot(u,y)
    temp=np.transpose(np.tile(w,(len(u),1)))
    div=np.divide(u,temp)

    r=np.tile(uDoty,(len(div),1))
    a=div*r.T
    c=sum(a)

    return c
```

and the result from

```
print np.allclose(Y,np.dot(K,c))
```

is false.

also the norm of difference from the true result is **3.13014997999**.

now I have no idea how can I fix this . I thought maybe some how by doing more precise answer.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

To solve *k c = y* with numpy, use `numpy.linalg.solve`:

```
c = solve(k, y)
```

This uses an algorithm that is much more robust than the methods you are trying.

Comment: yes I know, actually I want to implement the same algorithm on you , so I am interested to see how it works.DO you have any idea at which point I need more attention?

Comment: numpy.linalg.solve is a wrapper of the LAPACK [http://www.netlib.org/lapack/] routine DGESV [http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesv.f] (or ZGESV in the complex case).  DGESV use an LU decomposition [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition] to solve the system [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations].  The links and references in the wikipedia article can get you started learning more about the numerical solution of systems of linear equations.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that ..but I am just trying to make this code works for some reason.But cant understand what is wrong with my code